# Signalr Chat App not working with WebSockets on Azure

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr

My MVC SignalR Chat app on azure was working fine for the past few days but all of a sudden it stopped sending or receiving chats I discovered that when i turn off websockets everything works ok , turning websockets on again it all stops working what could be the problem? I ddnt change anything by the way or send any new updates to my app.